# Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (for nested objects)

Tags: reactjs

in my react component I have an object `user` which looks like

```js
{
  _id: xxx, 
  stats: {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},
  shops: [s1, s2, s3] // s1, s2, s3 are all objects
  ...
}
```

And then in my code I specify that it is an object.

```js
export class UserComponent extends React.Component<void, Props, void> {
  static propTypes = {
    user: PropTypes.array,
    fetchProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchProfile();
  }

  render () {
    const { user } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className='container text-center'>
        {user}
        <Link to="/">homeE</Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

But when I run the code the error message says:

`invariant.js:39 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {thumb, path, photo_id, shop_id, message, _id, date_added}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.invaria....`

it seems that I can do something like `createFragment(user)`. But this is not working for me because this object has a lot of nested objects like the above.

Does anyone know how do solve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In that line you pass value of `object` type.

```js
  <div className='container text-center'>
    {user} // this is an object
    <Link to="/">homeE</Link>
  </div>
```

In your case `user` must be a `string` type or `React component`(created by `React.createElement`) or `array` type of `React elements`.

If you need to render some data from user or pass it to another component, you can do so:

```js
  <div className='container text-center'>
    <User data={user} />
    <Link to="/">homeE</Link>
  </div>
```

And, of course, you have to define `User` react component, which handle(render) properties of user object. In `User` component we can get `user` object through `this.props.data`

Comment: yes but I want it to remain an object because a user have so many nested properties. can this work?

Comment: `render` method of component only responsible for render `view`. It is not for storing or calculate some data. What exactly do you want to do with `user` object? You can convert it to a string and then show to user all its keys and so on.

Comment: user is the loggedin user info. it will have tons of properties like name, id, image..etc.  Also on the same page there will be components that takes user.reviews, user.stats, user.messages, user.checkins for rendering. Also users have some properties like stat which is just a nested object.

Comment: I edited the answer. You can pass `user` object to another component if its needed.

Comment: Oh I got it. I was expecting to see the entire json on the page without any rendering.. Maybe that's just Angular... Thanks!!